# How to put packages inside another packages in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

My current project structure is

```
package
|
 - __init__.py
|
 - minipackage1
   |
    - __init__.py
    - file1.py
    - file2.py
 - minipackage2
   |
    - __init__.py
    - file3.py
    - file4.py
```

extrenal init looks like

```
__all__ = ["minipackage1", "minipackage2"]
```

and others like:

```
__all__ = ["file1", "file2"]
```

and

```
__all__ = ["file3", "file4]
```

But on running my script it says:

```
AttributeError: module 'package' has no attribute 'minipackage1'
```

So, where am I wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible you're referencing another package also called package? Modify the PYTHONPATH to look in the folder where you have this tree structure first.

Comment: not a variant, I've checked my environment lib folder, and all installed modules list, there's no package with same name

Comment: What happens when you `import package; print(package.__all__)`?

Comment: it says ['minipackage1', 'minipackage2'], I guess, that's because of my external __init__.py setup

Comment: “On running my script”… what does your script actually do (the imports) and where are you running it from?